# How to sort horribly seperated CSV? Commas in wrong place, 10k lines

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning

I've converted a pdf to csv using several methods, the best output was using tabula (others tried: tabula-pi, pdftocsv API). Maybe you have other suggestions for another method for the conversion?

The issue lies in unclear cell separations of the pdf, and several lines per cell. I will include a screenshot of said pdf here to illustrate.

[image: PDF Screenshot]

The CSV output looks something like the following bit of code. I cannot possibly sort through it manually, since there are 10'000 lines. I would need to automate it to sort out what's happening. CSV sample:

```
"1st of the
WorstWashington",Tacoma,"1970
unknown circulation
1st of the Worst was an antiwar paper published by local GI's. Topics included local news, discrimination against ..",,,
"3rd Bn. 6th
Infantry Fuck
West Germany Null
Sheet","1973
unknown circulation",,,,
"13th Moon
New York",Albany,"1973-1984
unknown circulation
13th Moon was a women's literary magazine that published work by female writers.",,,
"70's Biweekly China
Hong Kong","1970-1973
unknown circulation
70's Biweekly was a radical Marxist magazine for students and workers. It covered Chinese politics.",,,,
"79 Cent
```

So not much is right. When I open it us with pandas to inspect, here's what it looks like:

[image: Notebook view]

I feel like this is fixeable but none of my attempts have been successful. I've tried seperating City column in \r wth expand = True:

```
df[['Date', 'Circulation', 'Content']] = df.State.str.split('\r', expand=True)
```

But there aren't always 3 columns to separate into. I'd love some advice, some help, some pointers? So far it's a mess.

Comment: I don't think it's feasible to automatically correct the errors after the fact. Find a better PDF parser which identifies the zones in the text correctly. I have no particular recommendation but that's how I would approach this. Or of course, if you have access to whatever was used to produce these PDFs, parsing that instead is probably going to be a lot more fruitful.

Comment: Why don't you write your own parser?

Comment: @jurez How could I do that, using what? I've never done it so I'd need pointers as to where I should look! Thanks

Comment: You can do it with Python alone, you don't need any libraries for that.

Comment: The information in your sample is already destroyed. You won't be able to restore it without manual intervention or very strong assumptions. For instance, you would need your program to know that `WorstWashington` is not an actual name, that it should be split to `Worst Washington`, and then that `Worst Washington` is not a 2-word proper noun but an adjective with the proper noun behind and thus `Worst` should be moved to previous column.